# TFS group permissions: Allow anyone in group to force push on branch created by group

Tags: git, tfs, permissions

my team and I have a dev branch that we are using. It is branched off of master - which we are not touching. All work my team and I do, is on feature branches that we create off of the dev branch.

Is there a way to set up permissions so that anyone on my team can force push over any branches that any of us create, but not any branches that others create, or master?

Currently we can all force-push over branches that we ourselves have created, but not over any branches that each other have created.

We are working with a different team who owns master and they don't want to give us the ability to force-push over master, but we use force-push in our workflow, and it's rather disruptive to have to wait until the branch creator force-pushes rather than force-push for them sometimes.

I've not used TFS much before, but couldn't find a way to do this with the searching/poking around I had done in the UI and on google.

Anyone know if this is possible?

thanks!

Comment: Does the dev branch  only for your team or other team also need working on it?  Does your team in a fully independent TFS group or all of you in the contribution group of the project?

Comment: The dev branch is only for our team. I don't believe we have actually been added as an independent TFS group yet. We were all just added to the generic 'contributors' group and our team group. We're using TFS server 2013 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other team can setup Branch Policies that protect MASTER and any other branch and prevent push without going through a pull request model.

If this is configured they can give you permissions while protecting some branches.

**I think that you need TFS 2015 for Branch Policies.**

Comment: I think you are totally correct! I remember reading about permissions that any 'deny' will overwrite any 'allow' permissions. I would think if they 'deny' us the capability to force push over master, but allow it for all other branches, that would work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to go to your TFS console  to allow the rights :

[image]

Comment: What TFS console are you referring?